# Strange behaviour of Process.Kill when NOT using ShellExecute on C# .Net Core 7.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, process, shellexecute

Consider a Parent process called "**A**".

"**A**" will run a child process "**B**" with **ShellExecute=false**.

"**A**" will run a child process "**C**" with **ShellExecute=false**.

**Now the issue is here:**
If you **Kill** or **End Task** the process "**B**" , the process "**C**" will be killed too!

When i set `ShellExecute=true` the problem is solved!

Is it a bug or something?

Comment: Likely because B and C have the same "controlling terminal".  What OS is this on?

Comment: @BenVoigt : Windows 10 Enterprise , 22H2 , 19045.3930
But I have the same problem on other versions even on the Windows Server 2019 and 2022

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/attaching-to-a-console which describes how a console can be shared between multiple processes.  Other pages in that area describe how to leave a console process group, how to determine whether processes are sharing a console, etc.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thank you , but it seems like a Bug ,  When we kill the parent process ("A") it's logical that the child processes be killed too , but killing a child process should not affect on other processes , The controlling terminal or parent console of child processes is "A" , and the "A" process is alive !!

Comment: And I've realise that killing the "C" process will not kill the "B" process !

Comment: Well, "A" might be coded to ignore losing its controlling terminal (on *nix that would be a SIGHUP) while "C" has the default behavior of exiting the process when that signal is received.  Consoles on Win32 don't work in exactly the same way as controlling terminals, but the resulting behavior is often similar.

Comment: So , If you have any solution would you please describe it ? Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest calling `GetConsoleProcessList` to see if they're all bound to the same console.  If so, then read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-process-groups and try `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` flag.  Not easy to do from inside of .NET.  One could contemplate using a really thin "launcher" helper process written in C++ that configures things correctly and then execs the real child process executable.